# Magento 2: How to use Admin Elements / Widget?

Tags: magento2, widget

How can I use Admin/Elements/Widgets that I create?
They don't appear in the wysiwyg editor / add widget.

I thought I could use them in Static Blocks..?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to click on **Show / Hide Editor** button in order to see **Insert Widget...** button

[image]